# iJulia notebook (iPython) files

Tags: file, ipython, julia

In my iPython notebook with iJulia, is it possible to call (functions from) other files? Until now, I worked in one big .ipynb file using all methods, but it is getting too large. Is there a way to transport some functions to other files, in order to call them from there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define your functions in a `.jl` file and then `include` it in the notebook.

If you have a file called `test.jl` with the content:

```
function helloworld()
    println("Hello, World!")
end
```

you can then call it from the notebook and it will be evaluated. You can then use function defined in the file as normal:

```
In [1]: include("test.jl")    
Out[1]: helloworld (generic function with 1 method)

In [2]: helloworld()
Hello, world!
```

EDIT:
To run code from another `ipynb` file is much trickier because the code is emedded into the json of the notebook. If you really want to this function should work:

```
using PyCall
function execute_notebook(nbfile)
    @pyimport IPython.nbformat.current as ipyt
    open(nbfile) do f
        nbstring = readall(f)
        nb = ipyt.reads(nbstring, "json")
        for cell in nb["worksheets"][1]["cells"]
            eval(parse(cell["input"]))
        end
    end
end
```

It currently throws an error but it still appears to work. If you have a `test.ipynb` with the same `helloworld()` function defined you could then call it from another notebook with:

```
execute_notebook("test.ipynb")
helloworld()
```

I'd still recommend keeping code you are going to call from other places in a `.jl` file rather than in a `.ipynb` file. It is simpler and probably more robust.

Comment: This solution does not work for .ipynb files, which are used in iJulia notebooks. I get the following error message.          
_`-` has no method matching -(::ASCIIString, ::ASCIIString)
while loading C:****\temp.ipynb, in expression starting on line 1
while loading In[43], in expression starting on line 1
 in colon at range.jl:75
 in include at boot.jl:245
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:128_

Comment: No, it doesn't. Added edit for how to run code in another ipynb file.